# asp.net website host in ftp server assembly missing error

Tags: asp.net, website-hosting

I am getting the following error message:

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySqlConnection' could not be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I am using following code:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString)‌​;
```

Comment: MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);

Comment: It will be better if you add your code to the question.

Comment: MySql workbench 5.2, but didn't know which version is used in client side, because ftp server is not my server. it's client side server

Comment: are you including the mysql binary in the websites bin directory?

Comment: yes i add mysql binary in my bin directory, it's working local machine but only error occurs after host client side

Comment: for ftp file upload i use filezilla software

Comment: can u help this problem, i am beginner of that asp.net development,

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 52:         MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Kidzania_conn"].ConnectionString);

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the 'MySql' dlls in your output directory.

Comment: i am did not  access server folder, i change all permission but nothing will change